# How can I find average, sum and count of values of a single column in Pig?

Tags: count, sum, apache-pig, average

I have a variable car_age which hold the distinct values of the age of the car in the entire CSV file. How can I take the average of all the values? I need to replace the outliers with the average (or mean) of car_age values.
Here is what I am doing currently.

```
training_data= LOAD '/user/All_State_Insurance_Prediction_Dataset/sampled_training_dataset/sampled_training_set';
A1 = foreach training_data generate car_age;
B1= Distinct A1;
```

B1 holds the distinct values of car age. How can I find the average, sum and count of the values in B1? I didn't use Group By as I need those operations to be done on a single list of values.

Comment: how can you find average , count or sum without grouping, because all these functions are aggregate functions . you have to give one grouping column in apache pig

Comment: But what if I want average of all the values irrespective of the column, like for the above case? If its not possible, what will be the query be like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for doing average

```
training_data= LOAD '/user/All_State_Insurance_Prediction_Dataset/sampled_training_dataset/sampled_training_set' USING PigStorage();

A1 = foreach training_data generate car_age;

B1= Distinct A1;

B1_grouped = GROUP B1 all;

B1_avg = FOREACH B1_grouped GENERATE AVG(B1);
```

Similarly you can do for SUM and other aggregate function